# pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins not updating

Tags: plugin-development, updates, automatic-updates

I've implemented [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-license-controlled-update-system-doing-the-update--cms-22675) update class in my plugin, but for some reason the update banner isn't diplayed.

Within the class `Wp_License_Manager_Client` I have this code:

```
add_filter('pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins', array($this, 'check_for_update'));
```

that fire the function `check_for_update`, in particular the following line is called:

```
$plugin_slug = plugin_basename($this->plugin_file);

$transient->response[$plugin_slug] = (object) array(
    'new_version' => $info->version,
    'package'     => $info->package_url,
    'slug'        => $plugin_slug,
    'url'         => $info->package_url
);
```

This is the `var_dump($transient->response[$plugin_slug])`:

```
object(stdClass)#8891 (4) { 
    ["new_version"]=> string(5) "1.0.1" 
    ["package"]=> string(107) "https://example.com/api/license-manager/v1/get?p=my-plugin&e=foo@mysite.com&l=123456789%24" 
    ["slug"]=> string(47) "my-plugin/public/class-wp-api-client.php" 
    ["url"]=> string(107) "https://example.com/api/license-manager/v1/get?p=my-plugin&e=foo@mysite.com&l=123456789%24" 
    }
```

I replaced the values for privacy, but as you can see the object is correctly created.

The situation in the panel is the following:

[image]

As you can see from the image Wordpress show me that there is one update, but when I click on "updates", it says that all the plugins are updated. Also, I get the update badge notification only when I clear the cache.

What is going on?

PS: I'm testing this in my localhost with XAMPP and wordpress version is 6.0.1.

Comment: Which cache plugin you are using can you specify that.

Comment: @Prits I doesn't have any cache plugin

Comment: So what this line means " Also, I get the update badge notification only when I clear the cache. " can you explain a bit.

Comment: @Prits I usally clear the cache using the console -> network -> disable cache

Comment: That cache didn't create issue with this.

Comment: check where you setting the value for `$this->plugin_file`.
The plugin slug suppose to look like this `my-plugin/my-plugin.php`, but the dump shows `my-plugin/public/class-wp-api-client.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across this a few weeks ago with a client site - maybe this will help.

```
 /**
 * Debug Pending Updates
 *
 * Crude debugging method that will spit out all pending plugin
 * and theme updates for admin level users when ?debug_updates is
 * added to a /wp-admin/ URL.
 */
function debug_pending_updates() {

    // Rough safety nets
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) return;
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['debug_updates'] ) ) return;

    $output = "";

    // Check plugins
    $plugin_updates = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
    if ( $plugin_updates && ! empty( $plugin_updates->response ) ) {
        foreach ( $plugin_updates->response as $plugin => $details ) {
            $output .= "<p><strong>Plugin</strong> <u>$plugin</u> is reporting an available update.</p>";
        }
    }

    // Check themes
    wp_update_themes();
    $theme_updates = get_site_transient( 'update_themes' );
    if ( $theme_updates && ! empty( $theme_updates->response ) ) {
        foreach ( $theme_updates->response as $theme => $details ) {
            $output .= "<p><strong>Theme</strong> <u>$theme</u> is reporting an available update.</p>";
        }
    }

    if ( empty( $output ) ) $output = "No pending updates found in the database.";

    wp_die( $output );
}
add_action( 'init', 'debug_pending_updates' );
```

Append your admin url as follows:

```
For example: https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/?debug_updates
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-license-controlled-update-system-doing-the-update--cms-22675) you are using is 7 years old, I wouldn't bother wit it as it is probably not fully compatible with latest WP-Core and auto-updates.

I'm using free (MIT license) and regularly maintained [Plugin Update Checker](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker) & [WP Update Server](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/wp-update-server) WP libraries for my [Warp iMagick plugin](https://github.com/ddur/Warp-iMagick).

Check this [tutorial to add licencing](http://open-tools.net/documentation/tutorial-automatic-updates.html#wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if plugin updates is available :

```
add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'register_test_menu_page'));

public function register_test_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page('Test', 'Test Menu', 'manage_options', 
     'test_user_menu', array($this,'test_user_menu_fun'), null, 4);
}

public function test_user_menu_fun(){
    $update_plugins = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
    foreach ($update_plugins->response  as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($value->slug);
    }   
}
```

it provides an array you can easily show that in the list in your setting page.

Comment: The code you provided returns an empty response, but as you can see from my question the transient is correctly valorized

Comment: Can you check your wp_options table with the key '_site_transient_update_plugins' and double check if you see in correct database and also add the SS for plugin update available .

Comment: The value of `_site_transient_update_plugins` is the following: https://pastebin.com/WLZQeTQP also I don't know what does SS means

Comment: The link is not available and add SS means Screenshot of that meta key wp_options table.

Comment: here we go: https://controlc.com/782d5ddf and here the ss: https://i.imgur.com/SHlYhGZ.jpg

Comment: Your _site_transient_update_plugins response shows empty that's why it shows empty in wp-admin can you check plugins ( Update available ) is there any list available and if yes can you mention the name of that plugin with that version which has updates because it works for me as i have 3 plugins to need to update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139253/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-prits).